# Удалить файл без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Помогите найти ошибку. Не работает конструкция.

Js:

```
 function delete() {
      var msg   = $('#closed').serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'submit.php?delete=<? $filename ?>',
          data: msg,
          success: function(data) {
            alert("Файл удален");
          },
          error:  function(xhr, str){
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });
```

Php:

```
$dir  = 'downloads';
$files = scan_dir($dir);
if($files == false) printf("Каталог пуст");
else { printf("<table  class='bordered'>
<thead>
    <tr>       
        <th>Название файла</th>
        <th>Размер</th>
        <th>Удалить</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>"); }

foreach($files AS $i => $filename) {
printf(
    '<tr><td><a download href="/downloads/%s" style="color:black">%s</a> </td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">%s</td><td><form  action="javascript:void(null);" id="closed" method="post"><button  onclick="delete()">del</a></form></td></tr>',
    urlencode( $filename),
    $filename,
    human_filesize(filesize( $dir . '/' . $filename)), urlencode(  $filename), $filename
);
}
```

submit.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['delete']))
{
unlink("./downloads/".$_GET['delete']);
}
```

В идеале, должен удаляться файл, ссылку на который нажал пользователь, не перезагружая саму таблицу.

Comment: Вообще-то получается, что Вы удаляете один и тот же файл всегда. имя файла как параметр `delete()` не передается....

Comment: укажите в `unlink()` абсолютный путь к файлу

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте `$_GET` на `$_POST`

```
if (isset($_GET['delete']))
{
unlink("./downloads/".$_POST['delete']);
}
```

А также нао передавать имя файла как параметер `delete()`

```
printf(
    '<tr><td><a download href="/downloads/%s" style="color:black">%s</a> </td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">%s</td><td><form  action="javascript:void(null);" id="closed" method="post"><button  onclick="delete(%s)">del</a></form></td></tr>',
    urlencode( $filename),
    $filename,
    human_filesize(filesize( $dir . '/' . $filename)), urlencode(  $filename), $filename
);
```

И JS функцию чуть поменять:

```
function delete(filename) {
  var msg   = $('#closed').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'submit.php?delete=' + filename,
```

Comment: Нет, тоже не работает